# Get jQuery value without needing `then` or `each`

Tags: cypress

I'm hoping someone can help, but I've posted this as [a Cypress discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/23454) as well, although it might just be my understanding that's wrong

I need to get the `Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>` of the cell of a table using the column header and another cell's value in the same row.

Here's a working example jQuery TS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6w1r7ha9/

My current implementation looks as follows:

```javascript
static findCellByRowTextColumnHeaderText(
    rowText: string,
    columnName: string,
) {
  const row = cy.get(`tr:contains(${rowText})`);
  const column = cy.get(`th:contains(${columnName})`)
  const columnIndex = ???
  return row.find(`td:eq(${columnIndex})`)
}
```

This function is required because I want to write DRY code to find cells easily for content verification, clicking elements inside of it etc.

The only example I've seen is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70686525/1321908, but the following doesn't work:

```javascript
const columns = cy.get('th')
let columnIndex = -1
columns.each((el, index) => {
  if (el.text().includes(columnName) {
    columnIndex = index
  }
  cy.log('columnIndex', columnIndex) // Outputs 2 as expected
})
cy.log('finalColumnIndex', columnIndex) // Outputs -1
```

My current thinking is something like:

```javascript
const columnIndex: number = column.then((el) => el.index())
```

This however returns a `Chainable<number>` How to turn it into number, I have no idea. I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850775/1321908) to guide my thinking in this regard.

Comment: `then` would not work for you case either?

Comment: I need to return the value, so if I could `await` that `then`, definitely!

Comment: `then((el) => el.index())` returns a `Chainable<number>`, how do I unchain it?

Comment: you can 'unchain' it only by using a `then` (or `should`) callback. 
`await` is not officially supported for Cypress chains. there is a `cypress-promise` plugin with some limited support for awaiting chains.

Comment: you can also try `cypress-thenify` plugin (I'm the author). it has some limitations as well =)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Using `.then()` in a Cypress test is ***almost*** mandatory to avoid flaky tests.

To avoid problems with test code getting ahead of web page updating, Cypress uses `Chainable` to retry the DOM query until success, or time out.

But the `Chainable` interface isn't a promise, so you can't `await` it. You can only `then()` it.

It would be nice if you could substitute another keyword like `unchain`

```js
const column = unchain cy.get(`th:contains(${columnName})`)
```

but unfortunately Javascript can't be extended with new keywords. You can only add methods like `.then()` onto objects like `Chainable`.

---

Having said that, there are code patterns that allow extracting a `Chainable` value and using it like a plain Javascript variable.

But they are limited to specific scenarios, for example assigning to a global in a `before()` and using it in an `it()`.

---

If you give up the core feature of Cypress, the automatic retry feature, then it's just jQuery exactly as you have in the fiddle (but using `Cypress.$()` instead of `$()`).

But even Mikhail's `thenify` relys on the structure of the test when you add a small amount of asynchronicity

**Example app**

```html
<foo>abc</foo>
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const foo = document.querySelector('foo')
    foo.innerText = 'def'
  }, 1000)
</script>
```

**Test**

```js
let a = cy.get("foo").thenify()
// expect(a.text()).to.eq('def')           // fails 
// cy.wrap(a.text()).should('eq', 'def')   // fails
cy.wrap(a).should('have.text', 'def')      // passes

let b = cy.get("foo")                      // no thenify
b.should('have.text', 'def')               // passes
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your working example, you will need to get the headers first, map out the text, then find the index of the column (I've chosen 'Col B'). Afterwards you will find the row containing the other cell value, then get all the cells in row and use .eq() with the column index found earlier.

```js
// get headers, map text, filter to Col B index
cy.get("th")
  .then(($headers) => Cypress._.map($headers, "innerText"))
  .then(cy.log)
  .invoke("indexOf", "Col B")
  .then((headerIndex) => {
    // find row containing Val A
    cy.contains("tbody tr", "Val A")
      .find("td")
      // get cell containing Val B
      .eq(headerIndex)
      .should("have.text", "Val B");
  });
```

Here is the [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/findCellByOtherCellValueAndColumn.md).